# Move a renderUI object from flexdashboard to shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

First I have the code that creates a flexadashboard. When the user selects a button the relative pop-up message is enabled. As you can see everything happens inside a `renderUI()` object. The issue is that I do not know how to create the same result within a shiny app since I cannot use the `renderUI()` like this inside the `server.r` part.

## flex

````
---
title: "Single Column (Fill)"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

### Chart 1

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
               choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
               selected = 1)

renderUI({


if (input$radio==1) {
  #paste("The following tickers already exist in the database:", bad_tickers, collapse = " ")
  sendSweetAlert(session, title = "Bad tickers", text = paste("The following tickers already exist in the database:"))
} else if (input$radio==2) {
  #paste("The following names already exist in the database:", bad_names, collapse = " ")
  sendSweetAlert(session, title = "Bad Names", text = paste("The following names already exist in the database:"))
} 
  else {
sendSweetAlert(session, title = "Nice!", text = "Your tickers, names and weights have been saved. You'll see them appear as available funds if you refresh your browser.")



}
})



```
````

## shiny(not working)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Sweet Alert examples"),
  radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
               choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
               selected = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title = "1",
      text = "All in order",
      type = "success"
    )



    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title = "2",
      text = "It's broken...",
      type = "error"
    )

    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title = "3",
      text = "Non exist...",
      type = "error"
    )



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to translate your flex dash board into shiny, just create an actual `uiOutput` object in your layout and render it in the server function. (`renderUI` is a shiny function as well.)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Sweet Alert examples"),
  radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
               choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
               selected = 1),
  uiOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$result <- renderUI({
    if (input$radio==1) {
      #paste("The following tickers already exist in the database:", bad_tickers, collapse = " ")
      sendSweetAlert(session, title = "Bad tickers", text = paste("The following tickers already exist in the database:"))
    } else if (input$radio==2) {
      #paste("The following names already exist in the database:", bad_names, collapse = " ")
      sendSweetAlert(session, title = "Bad Names", text = paste("The following names already exist in the database:"))
    } 
    else {
      sendSweetAlert(session, title = "Nice!", text = "Your tickers, names and weights have been saved. You'll see them appear as available funds if you refresh your browser.")
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: OK thats the answer

Answer (score 1):

Put all the `sendSweetAlert` calls (and the code to figure out which one to send) inside `observeEvent(input$radio, { ... })`

```
  observeEvent(input$radio, {
    switch(input$radio,
     `1`= sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "1",
        text = "All in order",
        type = "success"
      ),

      `2`=sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "2",
        text = "It's broken...",
        type = "error"
      ),

      `3`=sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "3",
        text = "Non exist...",
        type = "error"
      )
    )
  })
```

Comment: thanks but I would like to avoid observer for my actual case

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use an observer? `sendSweetAlert` doesn't actually need (or use) a corresponding UI element.